# How to save data and reload the page with one button (Click)

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, asp.net-mvc-4

I am saving a data with this button

```
 <p><input type="Submit" value="Save" id="Save" /></p>
```

Is this possible that it also reloads the page at the same time.

I am using this code.

```
  <script type ="text/javascript">


        $('#Submit').click(function () {
            location.reload();
        });

</script>
```

But it is not working. It only saves the data.

Comment: If you just want to use location.reload(); then why can't you just return the same view again from your action method?

Comment: as you are returning json, so are you using ajax form??

Comment: also please post your complete view it is not enough infornation and also action

Answer (score 0):

You can do this in two ways:

1. Forget about JavaScript and make the MVC action return a Redirect response to the page you are coming from.
2. In stead of type="submit" create a button and attach an event handler which makes an AJAX request and reloads the page when the request has completed. Notice that this solution costs an extra server round trip compared to option 1.

Example for option 1:

```
return Redirect("Controller", "Action", additionalParamsObject);
```

Comment: I am already returning using jason another view. And the above view is the partial view of that that view
 
     return Json(new { ok = true, newurl = Url.Action("CreateNote") });